# Naming of bool methods: Is vs. Can vs.?

Tags: naming, naming-standards

Which is the better name for a method that returns a boolean?

```
IsSupportContentType
```

or

```
CanSupportContentType
```

Comment: Since the intent is for the name to clearly convey state or behavior, and you would never say "this class is support content type X," the better name is CanSupportContentType. You would say something like "this class can support content type X."

Comment: @Craig Unless the class is `ContentType` and some content types are support content types, of course - in which case `IsSupportContentType` would return true if the receiver is a support content type. But support**ed** is a different word entirely.

Comment: Not a native speaker but wouldn't *Does*SupportContentType be the most "grammatical" option?

Comment: @RomanReiner That's already better grammar than more than one native speaker I know.  :)

Comment: @immibis That is a fair point. I find myself compelled to agree with you, without inheritance or polymorphism even needing to necessarily play a part.

Comment: What kind of method are we even talking about? A getter type method or a query type method? Maybe a processing validation?

Comment: First one would have to be `IsSupportedContentType` to be grammatically correct. (unless "support content type" acts as a noun, which seems unlikely)

Comment: What about simply `supportsContentType`? The following is entirely readable: `if (abc.supportsContentType("text/html"))`. "can support" implies that there are further conditions to support the content-type.

Comment: I agree with Olivier. `SupportsContentType` is the best choice. It is simpler, shorter, and reads better in a wider variety of statements. In general, when it's a toss-up like this, I look at how I expect the function to be called, and pick the one that ends up being the most readable with the surrounding code. The client of the library will either have to look it up or use IntelliSense anyway, so you might as well shoot for readability of the resulting code for future maintainers.

Comment: You didn’t specify a language.  [Standards vary widely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_convention).

Comment: You can always use both. IsCanSupportContentType. I use both so that my code stands out. People know when I've been refactoring their code, they are delighted and I gain recognition.

Comment: The capital first letters suggest that this is about C#, but it may be worth mentioning that for Java, there is another important point to consider: The `is` prefix is assumed for Java Beans, and expected by the introspectors. So in Java, you should usually use `is` as the prefix for "getters for `boolean` values".

Comment: @WeylandYutani IsCanHasSupportCheezburger?

Comment: Conventions vary by language, and I'm surprised not to see a tag. For instance, in many LISP-family languages, the standard way to specify that a function has a boolean is to have its name end in a `?` -- so, `(defn support-content-type? ...)`

Comment: Best practice for boolean-returning methods/functions is [to not write them](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/) in the first place.

Comment: `IsContentTypeSupported`?

Comment: @WeylandYutani I'd be far from delighted if you'd renamed a method I'd written to something so horrendous.

Comment: IsContentTypeSupported?

Comment: @megaflop He's gotta be onto *something* considering they've already cornered the synthetic market through superior engineering.

Comment: I prefer a trailing `?`, or if that's not available, a trailing `-p`.  (`p` for "predicate".) For benighted languages I use a prefix `p` or `q`.

Comment: Has anybody else noticed how, over the years, this discussion has turned form „naming convention wars“ into a fruitful and respectful exchange of arguments as exemplified by this questions, it’s answers and it’s comments?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**Is vs. Can**

According to the [Microsoft naming convention recommendations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012(v=vs.110).aspx), both "Is" and "Can" are OK (and so is "Has") as a prefix for a Boolean.

In plain English, "Is" would be used to identify something about the type itself, not what it can do.  For example, `IsFixed`, `IsDerivedFrom`, `IsNullable` can all be found in CLR types and methods.  In all of these cases, "Is" is followed by an **adjective**.

Meanwhile, "can" more clearly indicates a capability, e.g. `CanEdit`, `CanRead`, `CanSeek`.  In each of these cases, can is followed by a **verb**.

Since "Support" is a verb, I think in your case `CanSupportContentType` is better.

**Shorter alternative**

On the other hand, the conventions say the prefix is optional.  What's more, it's kind of cheesy to include the argument type in the method name, since a developer can see the type of the argument in intellisense.  So you *could* just name your method `Supports` and define it like this:

```
public bool Supports(System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType)
```

...which is shorter and still clearly communicates the purpose.  You'd call it like this:

```
ContentType contentType = new ContentType("text/plain");
var someClass = new MediatorsClass();
bool ok = someClass.Supports(contentType);
```

Or as a compromise maybe this is best:

```
public bool CanSupport(System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType)
```

Comment: It's nice when it reads well: `if ( someClass.Supports(contentType) )`

Comment: …or `hasSupportedContentType`

Comment: A method called "CanSupports" initiallty mades me wonder who spent time to make the software able to support cans (as in tin cans). Just "Supports" is the better option, no doubt!

Comment: Could you add a TL;DR section that says, "Just name things so they read easily; stop worrying about it before you make it sound weird."?

Comment: Sometimes developers can't tell when something "sounds weird," e.g. if English is not their first language.

Comment: Sometimes a shorter version is worse. E.g. in the C++ Standard library we have `std::vector::empty()`. From its name only, does it empty the vector? Or does it return whether the vector is empty? Actually the latter, since the former task is done by `std::vector::clear()`. But you must in general read the docs to be sure. As an opposite example, Qt's `QVector` is easier to understand in this regard, since its method of checking for emptiness is `QVector::isEmpty()`.

Comment: Has anyone used the "are" instead of "is" prefix? Ex: AreAllSelected vs IsAllSelected? I like the "is" but shouldn't I care about grammar? Or is there a better way to write them plurals?

Answer (score 19):

It's worth mentioning that the "**should**" prefix can also be used. According to [Apple's guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html), not just "**can**" and "**should**", modal verbs in general can be used to name functions that return boolean. I can't see many use of "**will**" but "**should**" is nice for advice-inquiring hooks, as seen in reactjs:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: (newProps: any) => boolean
```

Comment: **should** is imho pretty poor naming, "well, it _should_ close the document, but i'm actually not quite sure"

Comment: @lovis: I think Harry's comment is very valid. For example, I could delegate some database-related actions through a plugin layer, each plugin has a "ShouldCloseConnection" method which informs the framework that some cleanup should be performed. Just an example, but "should" is definitely a valid prefix.

Comment: @greg How is that less ambiguous than `WillCloseConnection`?

Comment: @Lovis We generally use `is...` but use `should...` in some function argument names, places where the boolean indicates *what the function is supposed to change things to*. If a function can optionally close a document, calling the parameter controlling that `isClosed` would be accurate (it’s not closed *yet*) and so we would use `shouldClose` to indicate that this is what the function is supposed to do. (Arbitrary example; we wouldn’t likely have a function like this, particularly since closing a document should be weighty enough to have a dedicated call.)

Comment: @Basic At least in our case, `will...` is reserved for asynchronous functions that return a promise; if the function described in my previous comment is synchronous, using `will...` would be inconsistent with our naming.

Comment: @KRyan if you agreed on those things it' s cool. Conventions beat everything else

Comment: -1 "Should" makes it sound like you're testing or asserting something.

Comment: The "should" prefix is only acceptable because it's part of the framework's API.
It only makes sense in react because react expects some components to have it.
But in user land object oriented classes it doesn't make a lot of sense.
React asks you (the creator of the class) if the component should update, but in framework-less code it doesn't happen that frequently.

Comment: How about "might" ? :)

Comment: More seriously, how would you prefix a boolean for some element that has to show, to be displayed: myButton.shouldShow, anything else?

Comment: "Should" is a completely valid prefix choice. There is no proper alternative to name a boolean which indicates whether the action should be executed or not. For example, ShouldDelete enables DB clean up. Just because it's longer than "Can" "Has" "Is", doesn't make it redundant or poor choice of words. Programming isn't a contest of variable shortening, they should be readable and easily understood. C++ std library is a great example of bad naming conventions, where you spend too much time reading the documentation.

Comment: @Lovis "Should" doesn't imply any uncertainty when used as a question, as it is here, i.e. "Should the component update?". "Should" seems like the best word to use for that question in plain English.

Comment: Lovis, when the user clicks to close a window, MacOS asks the app whether it _should_ close the window. Are there unsaved changes? When the app tells a user about it, do they save changes, lose their changes, or cancel the close operation? So once you understand the situation, the naming makes perfectly sense.

Comment: I've always considered anything in the right tense to indicate a question as fair game: `RequiresSupervisorPermission = MovingBackward || MovingMoreThanOne`. Sticking to only 'Is' as a prefix feels overly limiting, I'm interested in what others think

Answer (score 0):

For the people against the use of "***should***" prefix for boolean arguments, here is my fresh last one used for an optional argument name (but I need to agree that I can't even remember last time I've used this prefix):

```
MethodNameToUpdateDataList(..., bool shouldDeactivateMissingIds = false) {}
```

Neither "*is*", "*can*" nor "*will*" prefix seems ok there... What do you think?

Comment: And I forgot about the "Are" and "Has" prefix.

Comment: Another one: shouldAutoAllocateMovements.
Whaou, none for years and two used in the same day :D

Comment: Know I think that I understand, actually, most of the time, even with quite good coding practice when we use a boolean argument named without a standard prefix, we usually use directly the verb.
Also meaning that, everytime we see a case like this, that means that it could have been prefixed with "should".

Comment: What exactly does "should" indicate? Is there some logic behind this method that sometimes deactivates IDs? If not, the should prefix is redundant and misleading.

Comment: @kiwiron: The anwser to your question: "Is there some logic behind this method that sometimes deactivate" --> is Yes !

That is why, the caller of this method has to decide (himself) or let default but, he can force to true in some cases.

The method itself doesn't know yet when to do it or not, but the method still handle both logics.

The caller is the one knowing when here.

Comment: Why just not `deactivateMissingIds`? I don't want to tell it that it *should* do this thing. Just do the thing if it's relevant!