# Booleans Naming conventions : How to prefix a "show" boolean?

Tags: naming, naming-standards

I've seen [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/348659/335260) that it was a dividing topic to use "should" as a prefix for a boolean because it could mean that we're unsure.

Then how would you prefix a boolean such as "myButton.shouldShow"?

I feel indeed that it's a little bit weird so I was hoping to find another solution.

Answer (score 7):

I will use:

- `myButton.canBeShown` if I want to know whether the button can be shown or not.
- `myButton.isShown` or `myButton.isVisible` to know whether the button is currently showing or not.
- `myButton.isAlwaysShown` to know whether the button must be shown everytime or not.

Answer (score 3):

you are using a verb to describe state (show) which I think is where the problem arises. if possible I'd change it to isVisible or similar

Comment: `is` is a verb too.

Comment: oh yes, hmmm, show still seams wrong though but now i'm not sure why

Comment: I'm being a little unfair as "show" is just a verb, whereas "isVisible" is a verb and adjective. I know that a lot of folk like to use `is` and the like for booleans. I personally dislike them and would just go with the adjective, `Visible`.

Comment: I would go a step further and name it somethingIsVisible where something is replaced with the thing that is visible or not.

Comment: @AdamB usually that thing would be the object that isVisisble is a member of so that would be somewhat redundant

Comment: @jk true if it's a field that applies to the whole object being visible then yes, it would be redundant. Good point!